# Karaf Cellar distributed architecture

Tags: apache-karaf

I am developing an IoT application (it controls EnOcean devices). I have N servers controlling the devices and one management application, which manages and configures the devices associated with each server.

The servers are basically identical, but hold different device data. Their basic functionality is configured in Maven: I don't expect to reconfigure from Karaf's command line.

Is this an appropriate application for Karaf Cellar?  I can see that Cellar would help with the configuration of the N servers, but can I include the management app in the same cluster? Or is the Cellar philosophy more that the management function should also be replicated across all N servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karaf Cellar usually does a full replication for all nodes within one group. So what you could do is, create two different types of groups. One group containing your N servers, while the other group has only one "Management" node with it. 
For communication across group boundaries, use the Cellar Distributed OSGi. That way you can have specific services located in one group as providing services while the consumer can be in the other one.

In future please ask at the karaf users mailinglist, as it has much more people answering :-)

Comment: Thanks for this and for making me aware of the Karaf Users mailing list.

Comment: with the new lists.apache.org you can also use it as a forum: 
https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@karaf.apache.org